# template template total specialization

Tags: c++, templates, generic-programming

A template template specification is like this:

```
template < template < class > class T >
struct MyTemplate
{
};
```

How am I supposed to create a total (or partial) specialization for this template? 
Is this possible?

Comment: ...Somewhere exciting!  I can't wait!

Comment: Who in the world voted to close, and why? This seems to be a perfectly legitimate, topical question.

Comment: @Jerry: If you saw the first 30 seconds of the question (where the vote was cast), it would make sense. It was just the code up to `{` with no question. I made the comment: "`}; // where are you going with this?`" to which @John replied. But it's fixed now. :)

Comment: @Jerry Somehow half of my question didn't showed up.. My mistake, sorry.

Comment: @scooterman: It's all okay. It's a good question, too.

Comment: Am I the only one who finds it extremely confusing that some (early?) edits don't show up as edits?

Comment: @jalf: The rationale or the mechanism?

Comment: @GMan: the mechanism. I'm not too sure on the rationale either, but it gets confusing when you see (or write) comments in response to information that is no longer there, in a question with no edit history.

Comment: @jalf: Ah. It's the first 5 minutes of the question (and answers), after that edits show. I think the rationale is that the time span is enough to fix those minor formatting errors, grammatical errors, etc.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Like this:

```
#include <iostream>

template <typename T>
struct foo{};

template <typename T>
struct bar{};

template < template < class > class T >
struct MyTemplate
{
    static const bool value = false;
};

template <>
struct MyTemplate<bar>
{
    static const bool value = true;
};


int main(void)
{
    std::cout << std::boolalpha;
    std::cout << MyTemplate<foo>::value << std::endl;
    std::cout << MyTemplate<bar>::value << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: GMan, there is a way to enforce on MyTemplate specialization what kind ot T bar should expect?

Comment: @scooterman: Well in your class you'd just use `bar<T>` and it'll work or not. If I'm understanding your question correctly.

Answer (score 3):

A specialization of this would, for example, be:

```
template<>
struct MyTemplate<std::auto_ptr> {
   // ...
};
```